# Execute javascript code in nodejs using spawn

Tags: javascript, python, node.js

I wrote below code in node js to execute python code and print logs and return output using spawn,

```
const { spawn } = require('node:child_process');
const ls = spawn('node', ['-c', "python code content will come here"]);
ls.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
  console.log(`stdout: ${data}`);
});
```

it works fine, but now i want to execute javascript code in the place of python code , can somebody have any idea how we can do it or my command is wrong.

Below is my code to execute javascript code

```
const { spawn } = require('node:child_process');

jscode = `var hello = function() {
  console.log("log from DB function!");
  console.log(`{"return":"Return from DB function!"}`);
};

hello(); 
`
const ls = spawn('node', ['-c', jscode]);

ls.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
  console.log(`stdout: ${data}`);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`-e, --eval "script"`](https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#-e---eval-script)(Equivalent to `-c` for Python) option which will evaluate the argument as JavaScript.

```
$ node --help | grep "\-e,"
  -e, --eval=...              evaluate script
```

So your javascript code should looks like this.

```
# out.js
const { spawn } = require('node:child_process');

jscode = `var hello = function() {
  console.log("log from DB function!");
};

hello(); 
`
const ls = spawn('node', ['-e', jscode]);

ls.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
  console.log(`stdout: ${data}`);
});
```

Running this function produces the following output.

```
$ node out.js
stdout: log from DB function!
```